# Are there any prayers right after Fajr?

Tags: salat, sunnah

Assalamualaikum everyone. As the question says please list all the Sunnah/Wajib prayers before or after the Fajr salat.

Answer (score 4):

We Aleykum Elsalam,

Before Fajr prayer there are only two raka'at Sunnah, [Source](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/19/59). But there is nothing after, for the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon Him) Had forbidden it until the sun has risen:

> The Prophet (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) had forbidden: the offering
> of prayers after Fajr till the sun rises.
>
> [Bukari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/36)

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we suggest you read the [FAQ](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq).  You have a Good start for your answer, but it is not complete.  Please provide reference to an authentic Hadith or a fiqh book to back up your answer, thank you.  We are looking forward to having you as an active member here.

Comment: `all the Sunnah/Wajib prayers before or after the Fajr salat`, this what I understood from the question

Comment: Ok my apologies, the question's title has been edited for clarity.  Please add citations or references to Hadith or Fiqh books to back up your answer.  You answer is good.